# Update a product variation stock status in Woocommerce from outside of the parent product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Because I have only one product, but with tens of variations, for an easy overview and management I put the '*product_variation*' post type posts (product variations) in a separate sub-page of the '*Products*' menu in admin:

```
/** Register custom arguments for the 'product_variation' post type **/
function product_variation_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if( 'product_variation' === $post_type ) {
        $args = array(
            'label'               => __( 'Product variations label', 'woocommerce' ),
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => 'edit.php?post_type=product',
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            //'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => false,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'show_in_rest'        => true,
        );
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'product_variation_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
```

Also, I added the product variations labels and stock statuses to the displayed columns:

```
add_filter( 'manage_product_variation_posts_columns', 'wc_product_variation_table_head' );
function wc_product_variation_table_head( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['variation_label'] = __('Variations', 'woocommerce' );
    $defaults['stock_status'] = __('Stock status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $defaults;
}

add_action( 'manage_product_variation_posts_custom_column', 'bs_product_variation_table_content', 10, 2 );
function bs_product_variation_table_content( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name === 'variation_label' ) {
        $test_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'attribute_test', true );
        echo $test_title;
    } else if( $column_name === 'stock_status' ) {
        $stock_status = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', true );
        echo $stock_status;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_variation_sortable_columns', 'wc_product_variation_table_sorting' );
function wc_product_variation_table_sorting( $columns ) {
    $columns['variation_label'] = 'variation_label';
    $columns['stock_status'] = 'stock_status';
    return $columns;
}
```

Then, I added a custom field '*Stock status*' to the '*product_variation*' post type:

```
function product_variation_metaboxes( ) {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    add_meta_box( 'product_variation_div', __('Stock status', 'woocommerce' ), 'product_variation_metaboxes_html', 'product_variation', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_product_variation', 'product_variation_metaboxes' );

function product_variation_metaboxes_html() {
    global $post;
    $stock_status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock_status', true );
    ?>
    <select name="stock_status_select">
        <option value="instock" <?php if( $stock_status == 'instock') echo 'selected'; ?>>In stock</option>
        <option value="outofstock" <?php if( $stock_status == 'outofstock') echo 'selected'; ?>>Out of stock</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}

function product_variation_save_post() {
    if( isset( $_POST['stock_status_select'] ) ) {
        global $post;
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'stock_status', wc_clean( $_POST['stock_status_select'] ) ); //is updated
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock_status', wc_clean( $_POST['stock_status_select'] ) ); //is NOT updated (solved)
    }
}   
//add_action( 'save_post_product_variation', 'product_variation_save_post' ); //tried this also
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_variation_save_post' );
```

The problem that I faced and I can't solve it, is that when I change the stock status ('*instock*' or '*outofstock*') of a particular product variation, accessed from the created dedicated sub-page of the '*Products*' menu, on post saving it is not saved/updated in the default '*_stock_status*' post meta, although it is saved without problems in a custom one (just '*stock_status*'). <strike>**How can I solve this?**</strike>

**UPDATE** [2021-07-01]

The above code is OK. The observed problem was produced by another function, now it has been solved. **However, I will be grateful for suggestions of code improvement.**